# How can I launch DHCP starvation attack in WLAN?

Tags: network, attacks, denial-of-service, ddos, dhcp

In WLAN, due to MAC association on Access Point (AP), I can't send the DHCPDISCOVER messages using random MAC addresses. But if I keep my original MAC address as the source ethernet MAC a and random MAC address in the CHADDR field of DHCP packet and send the DHCPDISCOVER message, it is passed by the AP and transmitted to the DHCP server on the wired side. But again, when the DHCP Server replies back with DHCPOFFER message, it extracts the CHADDR mac from DISCOVER message and make it as destination MAC address for DHCPOFFER message. When it reaches to AP, it directly drops that packet because that random MAC address is not associated to any device at all.. What to do, please help?

Note: Its working fine on the wired LAN.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must create a "fake association" first with that mac to the AP in order to be able to launch that DHCPDISCOVER message. It seems your access point is doing a "good work" protecting the network but it can be avoided.

Maybe you can create some kind of script to change the mac, create the association, and then launch the starvation attack.